# Is there a way to make layers for textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-baking, layers

I want to make hair for my cuboid character, I will be making multiple of these cuboid character and I would like to be able to reuse the hair as it would be a bit of a hassle to have it to redraw it every time or have to crop it out every time I make new hair.

[image: thing]

Comment: I don't really understand what are you asking for. Could you be more specific? Will hair be another mesh? Or do you want to add another image on top of this texture?

Comment: i just want to another image/texture to it but on a different layer, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I will make an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final & Overview:

[image]

If you want to have an easy process you should have proper **UV Mapping** for your object and two textures.

**Cuboid texture** - It could be anything you want.

**Hair texture** - Should be painted on transparent background.

When you have both of them you can **Mix** them trough **Inverted Alpha Channel** from your **Hair texture**.

### Blend file:

[image]

### Edit:

To switch between textures in **Texture Paint** mode go to **Slots tab** and select desired texture. Always save them after painting and don't forget to save image file (or pack it) in **UV Image Editor**.

[image]

Comment: @MiloPaolone, I've changed a little node setup. Also if my answer helped you consider accepting it and/or upvoting ;)

Comment: when ill get more then 15 rep ill do it :p

Comment: You can always accept it ;) Will you managed to make this texture setup?

Comment: Uh, how do i exactly choose what texture/image to edit?

Comment: @MiloPaolone Are you painting them by Texture Paint inside Blender?

Comment: Yeah, i never tried using anything else

Comment: @MiloPaolone check Edit in my answer.

Comment: i didn't get what you just said?

Comment: @MiloPaolone I've added information about switching between textures in my answer. At the bottom of it.

Comment: Uh, is there a way to do the same thing but material + texture? I'm trying to put the letter "O" on a olive for a logo thingy                                                      http://imgur.com/gallery/XOJmY